# How to display loading icon until pdf file is loaded?

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf

I want to show loading icon until pdf is loaded into the webpage.I have pasted what I have tried but loading icon keeps on displaying even the pdf is loaded fully. Got this code from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/selvadevel/BXe8C/375/)

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<style>
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid green;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
    var $iFrame = $('iframe'); 
    $iFrame.load(function(){
        $('h3').html('PDF Loaded!');
    });

    $('h3').html('Loading PDF...');
    $iFrame.attr('src', 'http://listic.ru/jQuery_Cookbook.pdf');


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3></h3>
<iframe></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console? i have tried running the code and i see the pdf url does take a while to load.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use an iFrame to display a PDF. If you want to embed a PDF onto a webpage, you should use a JavaScript library like pdf.js.

Anyway, use this http://jsfiddle.net/BXe8C/497/

The `$(document).ready(function() {` event fires as soon as the DOM (document) has downloaded.

The `$(document).load(function() {` event fires when all on page elements have completely loaded.

So use a JavaScript library like https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js to render the PDF, and use that jQuery event above to listen for when the page has completely loaded.

Comment: Apparently some browsers support PDF's in iFrames, but I wouldn't recommend it!